# ¿Como limpiar la terminal de java?

Tags: java, bluej

Existe alguna manera de borrar todo lo que aparece en la terminal de java despues de usar algun metodo con System.out.println();?

Comment: Java por sí no tiene una terminal. La terminal la ofrece el sistema operativo. Cada terminal funciona diferente. Quizás una solución funcione para Windows pero no para Linux o Mac.

Comment: ya veo, y sabes como seria el metodo para windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Investigando habia encontrado esta funcion:

```
public static void clearScreen() {  
System.out.print("\033[H\033[2J");  
System.out.flush();
```

}

Espero que te sirva a vos tambien.